# Flex Grow on .NETMAUI

Tags: c#, maui

Im trying to add a Grow 1 on my .NET MAUI .cs file, can someone please steer me in the right direction, here is the code for the whole file..

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Layouts;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PagesDemo
{
    public class FlexDemo : ContentPage
    {
        public FlexDemo()
        {
            Content = new FlexLayout
            {
                Direction = FlexDirection.Column,

                Children = {
                    new Label
                    {
                        Text = "HEADER",
                        FontSize = 18,
                        BackgroundColor = Colors.Aqua,
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    },

                    new FlexLayout
                    {
 // I need a grow here
                    }
                }
            };

        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Grow` is an attached property - they are much easier to use in XAML.  Is there a reason you're doing this in code and not XAML?

Comment: @Jason , I've already done XAML, Im just looking to explore different ways of doing things  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [FlexLayout extensions / Grow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/markup/extensions/flex-layout-extensions#grow) is this code snippet:

```cs
new Label().Grow(1f);
```

In your code:

- above `Content = ...`, make a local variable holding what you want to grow.
- Then add that variable to children.
- Finally set Grow afterwards:

```cs
var layout2 = new FlexLayout
{
    // contents
};

Content = new FlexLayout
{
    ...

    Children = {
        ...,
        layout2
};

layout2.Grow(1f);
```

NOTE: It might be possible to move `layout2.Grow..` line before `Content = ...`. I haven't tried it.